# Can guards find and arrest you in casing mode in a public area during a searching phase?

Tags: payday-3

In Payday 3, certain things can cause a Searching phase, such as a teammate being cuffed. During this phase, if you're caught in a private area in casing mode you will be cuffed instead of escorted out. Does the same thing apply in public areas? Can a guard arrest you just for being in a bank with an armor lined suit on, or do you also have to be trespassing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No**. Even if the guards are searching, you are completely safe in public areas if your mask is off.